# Excel: importing cell data to another sheet using the heading of the column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to take information from one sheet to another in the same workbook.

However, I would like the positive cells to be imported to the sub sequential sheets with the name of their column.

For example:

```
           |  Example1 | Example2 | Example3
-----------+-----------+----------+----------
List One   |     x     |          |   x
List Two   |     x     |    x     |
List Three |     x     |          |
```

So I would like

- in Sheet2 - ***List One***

  - Example1
  - Example3
- In Sheet3 - ***List Two***

  - Example1
  - Example2
- In Sheet4 - ***List Three***

  - Example1

Hope that makes some kind of sense to someone! Sorry for the terrible coding, rusty rusty rusty!

Comment: I still cannot understand what you are looking for. The values Example1..Example3 are listed in the first sheet and you are looking for a macro or vba code to dispatch the values in other sheets?

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood, your tags say excel-formula, but you also say coding is rusty, so I assumed you wanted a vba solution

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your titles are in row 1, and data starts in row 2

In the 1st column *(row doesn't matter here)* of your other sheets, enter this formula `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,SMALL(IF(2:2="X",COLUMN(2:2)),COLUMN())-1)` as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

copy this across the row, and it will list the column names. The end is reached when the formula starts giving `#NUM!` errors.

For sheet3, change the 2:2 to 3:3 and so on for subsequent sheets

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to have a longer number of rows and columns and assumes anything rather than just "x"
You may be sure it is always "x" and change this pretty easily.
Also I made this name sheets according to their list name. If adding sheets will not occur you can remove that part.

```
Sub columnsToListSheets()
LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
For rowNumber = 2 To 4
i = 1
    ListName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 1)
    Sheets.Add
     NewSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
      Worksheets(NewSheet).Cells(1, 1) = ListName
      'You may want to name the worksheet after the list
      Worksheets(NewSheet).Name = ListName

For colNumber = 2 To LastCol
                                                        '"x" may be good enough to test for
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, colNumber) <> "" Then
        i = i + 1
        'Worksheets(NewSheet).Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, colNumber)
        Worksheets(ListName).Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, colNumber)
    End If

Next colNumber
Next rowNumber
End Sub
```